# sinatra stopped loading files from public folder

Tags: ruby, sinatra, settings

I have set the public filder and it was working fine, but all of sudden sinatra stopped loading files from public folder,
I get 404 while trying to load css and javascript files
This is my config

```
    set :root, File.dirname(File.dirname(__FILE__))
    set :views, File.dirname(__FILE__) + "/../views"
    set :public_folder, File.dirname(__FILE__) + "/../public"
```

UPDATE:

This happens when my code is

```
    get '/' do
        if Sources.all.size>0 then
            haml :home, {:layout => :"home-layout"}
        elsif request.ip == "127.0.0.1" then
            redirect '/setup/sources'
        else
            redirect '/nothing-here'
        end             
    end 

    get '/setup/sources' do
        if Sources.all.size == 0 then
            @list=FOps.ls(Dir.home).to_json
            haml :setup, {:layout => :"nosetup-layout"}
        else
            redirect '/setup/files'
        end
    end
```

it wont work only with /setup/sources it works fine with /

when I replaced code 
with

```
    get '/' do
        if 0 < 1 then
            haml :home, {:layout => :"home-layout"}
        elsif request.ip == "127.0.0.1" then
            redirect '/setup/sources'
        else
            redirect '/nothing-here'
        end             
    end 

    get '/setup/sources' do
        if 0 < 1 then
            @list=FOps.ls(Dir.home).to_json
            haml :setup, {:layout => :"nosetup-layout"}
        else
            redirect '/setup/files'
        end
    end
```

it wont load js and css localhost:4567/setup/sources but it loads fine at localhost:4567

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was with relative path, it was fixed after using path from root